# Split one variable values of data frame according to levels of grouping variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, split, multiple-columns

How can I split one variable values as columns of the data frame according to the levels of the other grouping variable?

Suppose I have a data frame as shown below

```
Site Species dbh
1    sp1     2.8
1    sp2     2.2
2    sp1     4.0
2    sp2     1.5
3    sp1     3.9
3    sp2     2.5
```

I want to get the output as below in which the levels of the grouping variable (species) become columns of the data frame and dbh values as values for each level of the grouping variable.

```
Site sp1  sp2
1    2.8  2.2
2    4.0  1.5
3    3.9  2.5
```

I would be thankful for your valuable suggestions.

Regards,

Farhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a “reshape” or a “pivot”. There are hundreds of tutorials and SO questions out there about it.

```r
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
Site Species dbh
1    sp1     2.8
1    sp2     2.2
2    sp1     4.0
2    sp2     1.5
3    sp1     3.9
3    sp2     2.5")
```

With the `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyr)

dat %>% pivot_wider(values_from = "dbh", names_from = "Species")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>    Site   sp1   sp2
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1   2.8   2.2
#> 2     2   4     1.5
#> 3     3   3.9   2.5
```

With `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

dcast(dat, Site ~ Species)
#> Using 'dbh' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
#>    Site sp1 sp2
#> 1:    1 2.8 2.2
#> 2:    2 4.0 1.5
#> 3:    3 3.9 2.5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. It really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `reshape` if you are with base R

```
reshape(
  df,
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "Site",
  timevar = "Species"
)
```

which gives

```
  Site dbh.sp1 dbh.sp2
1    1     2.8     2.2
3    2     4.0     1.5
5    3     3.9     2.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your quick response is really appreciated.